# Debug a web service on a remote server

Tags: c#, web-services, debugging

I have a client application written on C# which is accessing a web service on a specific server. The web service is written as well in C# both on Framework 1.
I'm interested to debug the application and to enter the web service in debug mode. I want to follow and understand some procedure in that web server.
Do someone know if can be done?
Could I have some help?
Thanks
Flo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug Web Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581932/how-to-debug-web-service)

Answer (score 1):

you should enable the remote debugging, given the fact that your version of Visual Studio supports the feature.

check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=VS.80).aspx

and pay attention near the title at the selected version of Visual Studio, if you have another one select yours and read the article.

Comment: Thanks but is not much help I run Visual studio 2003 on XP machine and the web service is on Windows Server 2003