# How to debug Web Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I am using visual studio and I have asp.net application as one project and a web service as another project.I am using web service in my asp.net application. There is some sort of problem im my webservice code.But i am unable to debug continuosly from asp.net application to web service.I put break point both in application and web service but break point not activated in web service and it shows me connection error.How can i do this while hosting on localhost?

Comment: Are they hosted in IIS or by the VS test web server? If IIS, on local host or remote?

Comment: If you are getting a connection error then you are not reaching any of the code in the web service, that's why the breakpoints in the web service aren't being hit. Are you sure you have the address correct?

Comment: @Garland : both are on localhost

Comment: both IIS? Make sure you connect to the right w3wp (Application Pool process, different app pools mean different w3wp processes)

Comment: i am using visual studio asp.net development server.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're running web application as startup project, try running web service in another debug instance.

You can do it by right-clicking on web service project, Debug -> Start new instance

Comment: Perfect! I just tested it and it worked in single shot.

Answer (score 10):

You should attach the debugger to w3wp (IIS process).

Here is a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37182/Debug-your-ASP-NET-Application-while-Hosted-on-IIS) that could help you.

Comment: i am testing on asp.net development server.

Comment: have you set a break point in the method ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to debug in local system, You can set multiple start up projects.
You can set multiple startup by Solution properties.
Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Try to debug the service itself and see if it hits breakpoint. Just set the project that has service in it to be the main project and set the service to be the main start page.

If it doesn't hit the breakpoint it probably didn't load all the symbols. That happens if the project is set to, lets say, Release configuration and not Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Is the web service running on a remote computer , if so you need to setup remote debug for the web service.

Comment: Web service and application both are on same computer

Comment: is it a wcf web service ? if so you would need to enable debugging for it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157687.aspx

Comment: is it old school .net web service?

Answer (score 0):

Can You please check that you add Service reference  your web service or not other you can't access your web service function. I am useing web service in my project like this it's below

this is my web service code

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class JsonData : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(Description = "")]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public StateData[] GetStateByCountryID(int ID)
        {
            StateData objStateData = new StateData();
            LMGDAL.db_LMGEntities dbData = new db_LMGEntities();                
            var data = (from con in dbData.tblStates
                        where con.State_CountryID == ID
                        select new StateData
                        {
                            StateID = con.StateID,
                            StateName = con.StateName
                        }).ToList();
            return data.ToArray();
        }
```

then i add Service reference to my asp.net web form

this code in my form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
            var countryID = $("#ddlCountry").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JsonData.asmx/GetStateByCountryID",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{ID:"' + countryID + '"}',
                success: function (msg) {
                    var data = msg.d;
                    var stateData = "";
                    $.each(data, function (index, itemdata) {
                        stateData += "<option  value='" + itemdata.StateID + "' > " + itemdata.StateName + " </option>";
                    });
                    $("#ddlState").empty();
                    $("#ddlState").append("<option value='0'>-Select State-</option>");

                    $("#ddlState").append(stateData);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Faild To Retrieve States.');
                }
            });
        });
```

I think this will help you