# Is it possible to iterate a loop in an Asp.Net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a console application in which I am using an asp.net webservice.Also,I had declared a display method in my service which accepts and iterates a string array.But,when I executed the console application it showed an empty console window.Why the array contents are not being displayed?

Code that uses the below service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace usingWebServiceExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[3] {"harry","ronn","sheldon" };
            localhost.Service service = new localhost.Service();
            service.display(arr);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Service Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service()
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void display(string[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A side note - display should traditionally be capitalised to Display as it is a method.

Comment: You aren't running it as a console application.

Comment: Traditionally your Server should give you a list / array type result. You would generally call the service method from your console application and iterate and write the result on the client side. Services should not be used to display content, but to rather to retrieve information or perform an action.

Comment: did you by any chance, consider [attaching the debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581932/how-to-debug-web-service)? This is a much more efficient way to debug rather than trying to write to the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use  `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...)` instead of `Console.WriteLine()` for asp.net and you would be able to see the results in `output` window in the visual studio.

Writing log might does not make much sense here, you can return the array using [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public string display(string[] arr)
{
    return Join(",", arr)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A WebMethod operates on the Server not on your console app and so writing `Console.WriteLine()` there will write to the web project's console - not the application's.

If you look in your output window I suspect you'll see the values printed there.

In order to write the text out in your console window you'll need to return a string from your WebMethod and write it out in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either return an array of string to print to the client, or use duplex binding and  implement a callback on client side to print a message to console.

Here is a sample duplex callback implementation:
Server:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(IConsoleCallback))]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Display(string[] arr);
}

public interface IConsoleCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void WriteLine(string message);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void Display(string[] arr)
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IConsoleCallback>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            callback.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Server web.config:

```
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="wsDualHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    <add binding="wsDualHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
```

Client:

```
class Program
{
    class ConsoleCallback : ServiceReference1.IService1Callback
    {
        public void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] arr = new string[3] { "harry", "ronn", "sheldon" };
        var service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client(new InstanceContext(new ConsoleCallback()));
        service.Display(arr);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```