# Run Web app separately from Service Fabric

Tags: debugging, azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-debugging

I have Service Fabric and web service in it. If I run the Service Fabric locally, from Visual Studio, I can debug my service, and it is very convenient.

However, it takes a lot of time to deploy my code changes to local fabric. 
I am sure there should be an option to start my service separately from Service Fabric.
It seems I need to update my method 'Main', so that it starts the service differently in case of dev environment.

Any ideas what exactly should be changed?

Comment: Hi friend, do you mean you want to debug web service in visual studio without using Service Fabric? If so, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581932/how-to-debug-web-service) could help. If I've misunderstood anything, please feel free to correct me :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution, you can mark it as answer which benefit members with simlar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oleg Karasik's response helped to shape the solution. 
I do not use any Service Fabric specific features yet, so it worked out.

The only code I needed to modify was the class Program:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Fabric_ApplicationName")))
            {
                StartInIISExpress();
            }
            else
            {
                StartInServiceFabric();
            }
        }

        private static void StartInIISExpress()
        {
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .Build().Run();
        }

        private static void StartInServiceFabric()
        {
            < original code of the method Main >                   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your service use any of Service Fabric features (*Remoting? Custom Listeners? etc.*).

If **yes** then your service **cannot be run without Service Fabric runtime**.

In case you service is an ASP.NET Core service configured via `WebHost` then you can try the following approach:

1. Separate the code that configures `WebHost` into separate static method. Use this method to initialize `WebHost` inside Service Fabric service.
2. In the `Program.Main` you check for [Fabric_ApplicationName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference) environment variable (*this can be done using [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2) method*).

   > This variable is defined by Service Fabric runtime so if it is defined then you code is running inside Service Fabric.

   If the `Fabric_ApplicationName` variable is defined then just continue with the Service Fabric service initialization code, otherwise use previously defined static method to initialize and instance of `WebHost` and run it directly from the `Program.Main`.

I am not sure whether this is what you were looking for, so I you have any additional questions  - please ask.

Hope it helps.