# Remote debugging a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a VM machine and web service is installed there, running on IIS so if I open an IE window and type the address of my web service there, it shows it. 
Now I want to debug it from my local machine that has Visual Studio and the code.
Here is what I do:

- Open Remote Debugging Tool in Admin mode on VM machine.
- Open Debug->Attach to Process on my local VS, entered the name of the VM machine so it listed the processes running there.
- Should I see a w3wp process in the list? Because I don't see it there. So Is there something I am not configuring or missing?

Comment: Is [remote debugging enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7261513/542251)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dialog to attach processes there is a little check box at the bottom saying **"Show Processes From All Users"** , make sure it is checked.